# Even or odd program using modulo

Tags: ruby, modulo

I have a program:

```
def EvenOrOdd(number)
  if (number%2 == 0) then
    puts number + "is even"
  else 
    puts number + "is odd"
  end
end
puts "Please input a number: "
number = gets
EvenOrOdd(number)
```

When I input a number, it comes back that it is odd. I get an error, and I cannot find where my error is or what is wrong with my code.

Hopefully, you can help me.

Comment: Don't use PascalCase for method names. Should be snake_case: `even_or_odd`.

Comment: Get in the habit of writing `number.even?` and `number.odd?`. When compared to using modulo it reads better and is less prone to error. Those are the methods [Integer#even?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Integer.html#method-i-even-3F) and [Integer#odd?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Integer.html#method-i-odd-3F).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that `gets` returns a `String`.  You'll want to convert it to an `Integer`, for instance with `number = gets.to_i`.

While you're at it you should consider using `number.even?`, it's builtin and works like a charm.

Comment: And as added bonus: `.even?` crashes on strings :)

Comment: `Integer(gets)` would be more suitable as you can wrap it in a `begin..rescue` and not decide that `"asd"` is even :)

Comment: @MarcinKołodziej You're certainly correct, but I get the impression this is a case of recommending "small steps."

Comment: @pjs I understand, just wanted to mention that as I find `String#to_i` quite surprising for the unaware.